# cts:field-value-query to compare date

Tags: marklogic

```
<entry>
  <date>1971-12-23</date>
   <info>Some different information.</info>
</entry> 

cts:search(doc("/dates.xml")/root/entry, 
  cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("date"), "<=",xs:date("2000-01-01") ) )
```

If I have a field `rpdt`, how would I construct cts:field-word-query to compare date? I got an error code.

```
cts:field-word-query("rpdt", "<=", xs:date("1952-03-15"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a range index on the field and use `cts:field-range-query()`

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:field-range-query

Comment: I have "edatetime" is a field and datatype is date/time.  it works  cts:contains(fn:doc("datetime.xml"),cts:field-range-query("edatetime","=","2017-02-24T11:02:31.158-05:00")).  But not work cts:contains(fn:doc("datetime.xml"),cts:field-range-query("edatetime","=","2017-02-24")).  How construct to have yyyy-mm-dd only. Thanks

Comment: Please ask a separate question as it is not specific to the original problem statement.